# Setting up CRON on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, cron

The server has Ubuntu 12.10, and I tried to install `cron`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

The output of the second command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cron is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  php5-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Then, when I tried `sudo /sbin/chkconfig crond on`:

```
sudo: /sbin/chkconfig: command not found
```

`sudo /sbin/service crond start`:

```
sudo: /sbin/service: command not found
```

Is the `crond` located somewhere else? Or, do I miss something else?

Thank you

**EDIT:** the output of `ps -ef | grep cron`:

```
root       716     1  0 May30 ?        00:00:15 cron
deployer 26036 25816  0 10:59 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Comment: I think you are mixing things. Do `which service` or `which chkconfig` to know the exact path. Regarding cron, use also `which crond` to see where it is installed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I am not very familiar with Ubuntu and admin-stuff. `which service` -> `/usr/sbin/service`, `which chkconfig` -> nothing, `which crond` -> nothing. I am trying to set up CRON by this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps

Comment: OK then you need to do `sudo /usr/sbin/chkconfig crond on` and `sudo /usr/sbin/service crond start`.

Comment: Yes, I tried this (`sudo /usr/sbin/chkconfig crond on`), but got `sudo: /usr/sbin/chkconfig: command not found`. `sudo /usr/sbin/service crond start` returns `crond: unrecognized service`.

Comment: Can you try without the `d`? `sudo /usr/sbin/service cron start`?

Comment: Then: `start: Job is already running: cron` - so CRON is installed and set up, right? No I need to add only my cron jobs to `crontab -e` and this tasks will be run then automatically?

Comment: Good! You can see if it is running by checking all the processes you have. Do `ps -ef | grep cron` and in there it should show something like `00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -n`. And yes, `crontab -e` to edit, `crontab -l` to see the current values. You can debug with the info in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: Thanks, I added the output of `ps -ef` to the OP. Thank you very much `fedorqui` for your help! Please, feel free to add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: This worked for me: sudo /etc/init.d/cron start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in comments, and following the tutorial you mentioned [How To Use Cron To Automate Tasks On a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps), this is what you missed:

- Check where is your `service`:

  ```
  which service
  ```
- As it returned, `/usr/sbin/service`, then you have to use it to start cron:

  ```
  sudo /usr/sbin/service cron start
  ```
- This returned `start: Job is already running: cron` to you, so it was already running. In general, to know if it is running you can perform the command

  ```
  ps -ef | grep cron
  ```
- From this moment on, you have `cron` running on your server. You can edit it with `crontab -e`, see current values with `crontab -l`. You can test it with a dummy `* * * * * echo "hello" >> /tmp/test123`, that will write `hello` in /tmp/test123 every minute. In case of need, you can debug in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info.

Comment: One more thing - always when I upadte `crontab -e`, I get this message after saving the file: `crontab: installing new crontab`. Is that something I should be concern of?

Comment: It is fine and will appear until you save one crontab. It is the typical message you get when you are creating a new crontab for a user that did not have any before.

Comment: And the final question: the `test` example mentioned in the answer is working well. I've tried to add my own task: `12 * * * * curl http://www.website.com/my_task` and set up email where I should be notified after executing CRON tasks: `MAILTO="me@website.com"` - but the email has not come. (the email is obviously correct) Where could be the problem?

Comment: Don't post follow-up questions in comments.  Post a new question, but since this is not programming related, maybe try on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @user984621 it is important to firstly check if your command alone works. Then, make sure you indicate full paths (crontab has a limited environment). Check the debugging info in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info and, in case of no luck, you'd better ask a new question as tripleee said - this way, you will get an answer with more probability.